# Cast uint8_t-array to readable format

Tags: c++, arduino, ascii

I have this code, which receives a row of byte-values, inserted in an array. How can I show the content "readable" and not like this: R$⸮⸮>⸮⸮⸮

Here's the relevant code:

```
  // Read data from UART.
  uint8_t myData[8];
  String myDataString = "";
  int length = 0;
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_get_buffered_data_len(uart_num, (size_t*)&length));
  length = uart_read_bytes(uart_num, myData, length, 100);
  if (length > 0) {
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
      //SerialMon.write(myData[i]);
      myDataString += myData[i]+",";
    }

    SerialMon.println(myDataString); // should be something like "82,36,18,43,129,255,255,255"
  }
```

I believe the problem is, that a byte value like **82** in ASCII corresponds to the letter 'R' when displaying it as a character. Is there an easy way to convert the values, so that an element like **82** will show up as **"82"** instead... or even better: as HEX?

Comment: would `SerialMon.println(myData[i]);`help? or `myDataString.concat(myData[i]);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct with your assumption that `myData[i]` gets interpreted as ASCII-code, but you can easily convert it into a HEX-string as follows:

```
myDataString += String(myData[i], HEX);
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Much appreciated.